# Android Service: Stopself is not killing my app service

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, binding

I'm doing a Foreground service in my application, and when I'm calling the method `Stopself` inside the service it is calling my `OnDestroy` method but it's not killing my service. It still using memory, I check it through `adb shell dumpsys meminfo`.

I tried to call StopService too from my application but it's not working. I read a lot of posts from other people with the same problem, but they are using Handlers inside the Service. In my case I manage everything with a Singleton ThreadPool manager, that I already close with `shutdown()` method when app is closed.

It just happened when I close the app and my service still working. For example:

If I record a Fastmotion video and I wait until it is process, and later, I close my app. I don't have this memory lead. But, if I close the app then the service is processing this, It finish the processing, but I have a memory lead because Server is not killed.

So, hope that someone can see where it fails or what can I change to make this work. Here is my Service code:

```
/*
Base Service is a abstract class which implement the concurrent methods for the different services of the app
 */
public abstract class BaseService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BaseService";

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 10;
    private Notification mNotification;
    private boolean mIsNotificationShow = false;

    /**
     * mIsRegistered boolean controls when the application is in background or not.
     * Is set to true in {@link @ServiceConnection method}
     * Is set to false in {@link @unbindMediaSaveService()}
     */
    protected boolean mIsRegistered = false;

    /**
     * Count the number of request in the service to show the notification
     * and hide it when all of them are over
     */
    protected int mNotificationCount = 0;

    protected synchronized void showNotification() {

        mNotificationCount++;

        // Notification already shown.
        if (mIsNotificationShow)
            return;

        if (mNotification == null) {
            Bitmap bigIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            mNotification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.string_processing_notification_service))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_savephoto)
                    .setLargeIcon(bigIcon).build();

        }
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
        mIsNotificationShow = true;
    }

    protected synchronized void hideNotification() {

        mNotificationCount--;

        // Notification already hidden.
        if (!mIsNotificationShow)
            return;

        if (mNotificationCount == 0) {
            stopForeground(true);
            mIsNotificationShow = false;
            tryToCloseService();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set IsRegistered boolean to true or false to check in the service when the application is in background or not
     *
     * @param register set the boolean value
     */
    public void registerServiceClient(boolean register) {
        mIsRegistered = register;
        Log.i(TAG, "[registerServiceClient] Client registered: " + register);
        if (!register) {
            tryToCloseService();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to close the current service. It will be close if the application is in background{@link #mIsRegistered}
     * and the service don't have current actions{@link #mNotificationCount}
     */
    public void tryToCloseService() {
        Log.i(TAG, "[tryToCloseService] Trying to close Service");
        if (!mIsRegistered && mNotificationCount == 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "[tryToCloseService] Service stopped");
            stopSelf();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "[tryToCloseService] pending actions " + mNotificationCount);
        }
    }
}
```

I initialize a ServiceConnection and bind the service in my activity:

```
private ServiceConnection mMediaSaveConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder b) {
        mMediaSaveService = ((MediaSaveService.LocalBinder) b).getService();
        m

MediaSaveService.registerServiceClient(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            if (mMediaSaveService != null) {
                mMediaSaveService.setListener(null);
                mMediaSaveService.setPhotoListener(null);
                mMediaSaveService = null;
            }
        }
    };
 private void bindMediaSaveService() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MediaSaveService.class);
        startService(intent);
        if (mMediaSaveConnection != null) {
            bindService(intent, mMediaSaveConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            mMediaSaverIsBind = true;
        }
    }

    private void unbindMediaSaveService() {
        if (mMediaSaveService != null) {
            mMediaSaveService.registerServiceClient(false);
        }
        if (mMediaSaveConnection != null && mMediaSaverIsBind) {
            unbindService(mMediaSaveConnection);
            mMediaSaverIsBind = false;
        }
    }
```

Finally I call this methods in my `onStart` / `onStop` of my activity. Also, if it can help, in the services where I extend my BaseService, I put a `START_NOT_STICKY` flag to don't recreate the service when it's killed.

Comment: Why do you think your service is still running? stopSelf stops the service, that doesn't means it's destroyed, so it's normal it still uses some memory, unless Android decides to kill your process to clear memory it will be retained.

Comment: Before add the foreground service to my app when I killed the app, the applications threads die with it(running an adb shell ps | grep "package.name" I saw how my app was dead and no memory was allocated) but now it always still a remaining allocated memory, which means that something is still running(from my point of view, maybe Im wrong)

Comment: Do not worry about allocated memory. Instead, make sure that your process importance is appropriate. Use `adb shell dumpsys activity p | fgrep "package.name"`. While your foreground service is running, you should see a line with `(fg-service)`. Once you stop that foreground service, that same line should have something else (e.g., `(previous)`).

Comment: Yeah, it looks fine then: When its been processed the command line give me back:  Proc # 0: prcp  F/A/SF trm: 0 9222:com.my.camera/u0a116 (fg-service) And later: Proc # 0: prev  B/ /LA trm: 0 9222:com.my.camera/u0a116 (previous). So the allocated memory problem is a android memory leak?(I did the same with Other apps(google camera for example) and it let that allocated memory too

Comment: It's not a memory leak, it's how Android manages memory, your service class is retained in memory even if it's not running, in case your service is started again then Android will use the same instance. Android usually only clears a process memory when it needs more free memory, not when it's finished.